# Were there those who believed that the Hasmonean dynasty was messianic?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, messiah, heterodox

The majority branches of Judaism believes that the Messiah must be from the line of David. But were there other sectarian points of view? In particular, I am interested in the opinion about the Hasmoneans.

Comment: From a scholarly perspective, most of the books of the Prophets are thought to have been composed during the Hasmonean period.

Comment: That is not the scholarly consensus for most of the prophetic books. You can fairly say it about Daniel, but most of the others were already completed by this point.

Comment: "_The majority branches of Judaism believes that the Messiah must be from the line of David._" Isn't that what the prophets say?

Comment: I think this question turns based on what one means by messianic. A political and military savior of an oppressed people: absolutely that feeling was in the air. Messiah as in anointed with oil as a descendant of David, no, they were always honest about being descended from a priestly line, and that was one objection to that family as rulers.